# configurar apache nodejs proxy server

Tags: nodejs, apache2, proxy

He creado un programa con nodejs que funciona correctamente en http://ejemplo.com:3000/node/index.html pero quiero "ocultar" el puerto (3000).

He estado leyendo que necesito un servidor proxy, entonces configuré apache de diferentes maneras pero no logro conseguir mi objetivo.

Por ejemplo, tengo:

```
<VirtualHost ip:8443 ip:8080>     
ServerName ejemplo.com    
ServerAlias www.ejemplo.com     
DocumentRoot /home/www/  
ProxyPreserveHost On 
ProxyPass /node http://ejemplo.com:3000/ 
ProxyPassReverse /node http://ejemplo.com:3000/   
</VirtualHost>
```

AYUDA!!

Answer (score 0):

No es con el *apache* lo que querés hacer, tenés que cambiarlo en el archivo **hosts**.

Ruta en Linux o Mac:

```
/etc/hosts
```

Ruta en Windows:

```
C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

Y luego reescribir la ruta que querés cambiar, en este caso `localhost:3000`.

```
localhost:3000  ejemplo.com
```